# How to find a field from a class that holds a specific reference value efficiently?

Tags: java

I want to search what field from a class, given a bean instance and a value reference, holds that value reference. More specifically, says:

```java
public class Address { }

public class Person {
    public Address address1;
    public Address address2;
    public Address address3;
}

Address a1 = new Address();
Address a2 = new Address();
Address a3 = new Address();

Person person = new Person();
person.address1 = a1;
person.address2 = a2;
person.address3 = a3;

java.lang.reflect.Field field = SearchFieldByValue(person, a2); // Here, must return field Person#address2
```

I would like to do this using more performatic approach than iterating allover the fields and checking the values.

Comment: What type is `Field`? How is it related to `Address`?

Comment: There is no other way than iterating over all the fields and checking the value.

Comment: Write specific problem or in this case there is no solution other iterating.

Comment: For example, I could to create a class descriptor that holds field references by their types (a cache from field type -> field instance). By this way, I can reduce the time from iterating over all fields to iterate over that ones from the value reference type.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make a `List` of `addresses`?

Comment: This is just a hyphotetic scenario to ilustrate the problem. The fields could be of any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no more performant way to do this using reflection.

The performant way to do this would be to have each class (Java Bean or otherwise) that you want to be searchable implement a custom search API.

Or go further and create indexes for the searchable fields; i.e. implement a rudimentary in-memory database.  (For this to work, the cost of populating the indexes must be less than the cost of repeated searches.)

Comment: Yes, it's probably what I will do. Now, I need to think an efficient cache implementation.